# jq is not appending json file

Tags: text-processing, json, jq

I have a json file like this:

```
{  "active": "secure",  "secure": {   "nodetype": "secure",   "nodeid": null,   "servers": [    "ts2.na",    "ts1.na",    "ts3.na"   ],   "stakeaddr": null,   "email": null,   "fqdn": null,   "ipv": "4"  } }
```

I wanted to change it to something like this:

```
 "active": "secure",
 "secure": {
  "nodetype": "secure",
  "nodeid": null,
  "servers": [
   "ts2.na",
   "ts1.na",
   "ts3.na"
  ],
  "stakeaddr": "my nicea address",
  "email": "mynice@email.com",
  "fqdn": "itsmyfqdn",
  "ipv": "4"
 }
}
```

So, I tried this

> jq '.secure.stakeaddr = "my nice address"' config.json
>
> although it gives me this output:

```
{ 
        "stakeaddr": "my nice address",
        "email": null,
        "fqdn": null,
    }
```

But, when I cat config.json, it shows the last unchanged file. I tried with chmod 777 as well, same result. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jq` does not do in-place edits.

Instead:

```
cp config.json config.json.tmp &&
jq '.secure.stakeaddr = "my nice address"' config.json.tmp >config.json &&
rm config.json.tmp
```

This copies the file to a temporary file, applies the modifications to that (if the copying was successful) and redirects the result to the original filename.  Then you remove the temporary file (if the `jq` call was successful).

This would give you a new `config.json` file that looked like

```
{
  "active": "secure",
  "secure": {
    "nodetype": "secure",
    "nodeid": null,
    "servers": [
      "ts2.na",
      "ts1.na",
      "ts3.na"
    ],
    "stakeaddr": "my nice address",
    "email": null,
    "fqdn": null,
    "ipv": "4"
  }
}
```

To insert a value from a shell variable:

```
$ fqdn='Then she said "hello"'
$ jq --arg fqdn "$fqdn" '.secure.fqdn = $fqdn' file.json
{
  "active": "secure",
  "secure": {
    "nodetype": "secure",
    "nodeid": null,
    "servers": [
      "ts2.na",
      "ts1.na",
      "ts3.na"
    ],
    "stakeaddr": null,
    "email": null,
    "fqdn": "Then she said \"hello\"",
    "ipv": "4"
  }
}
```

That is, use `--arg variable value` to pass the `value` into `jq`, and then `$variable` within the `jq` expression.  Notice that doing it this way will *properly encode the value*.  Injecting the shell variable's value directly into the expression would not encode its value, and would possibly give rise to errors or a malformed JSON document.

Comment: Is there any for it to read global variable, like this?

```jq '.secure.fqdn = "$FQDN"' config.json.tmp >config.json``` But it didnt work for me.

Comment: @RakibFiha Sure, I'll add something about that soon (I'm not at a computer at the moment).

Comment: Cheers, eagerly looking forward to it. thank you.

Comment: @RakibFiha Updated.

Comment: jq --arg key1 $FQDN '.secure.stakeaddr.[$key1]' config.json.tmp >config.json

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.secure.stakeaddr.[$key1]                  
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: @RakibFiha With your example: `jq --arg key1 "$FQDN" '.secure.fqdn = $key1'`.  You should additionally double quote `$FQDN` as I have done here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not limited to jq only, here's an easy alternative - *[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)* allowing in-place modifications.

Assuming your source json is in file `config.json` then, for example, adding `"stakeaddr": "my nice address"` would look like this:

```
bash $ jtc -w'[secure]' -mu'{ "stakeaddr": "my nice address" }' -f config.json 
bash $ cat config.json
{
   "active": "secure",
   "secure": {
      "email": null,
      "fqdn": null,
      "ipv": "4",
      "nodeid": null,
      "nodetype": "secure",
      "servers": [
         "ts2.na",
         "ts1.na",
         "ts3.na"
      ],
      "stakeaddr": "my nice address"
   }
}
bash $
```

there's a number of ways to achieve the same. given the label `stakeaddr` already exist in the source json, then a better way would be:

```
bash $ jtc -w'[secure][stakeaddr]' -u'"my nice address"' -f config.json
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, this one seems very good way of doing it as well. I will try it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have `python`, which comes pre-installed in most *nix distributions, and the json file containing your data is named `file.json`, then following script

```py
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    jsonData = json.load(f)
pprint(jsonData)
```

would print a result similar to following:

```
{'active': 'secure',
 'secure': {'email': None,
            'fqdn': None,
            'ipv': '4',
            'nodeid': None,
            'nodetype': 'secure',
            'servers': ['ts2.na', 'ts1.na', 'ts3.na'],
            'stakeaddr': None}}
```

Comment: But, I am implementing this in shell scripting, that jq command  as @kusalanada showed in the comment can take multiple input in single line. Works really well in bash.

Comment: Problem is that it will create a temporary file to append it, which is fine I guess considering the simplicity.

Comment: @RakibFiha A for loop can be added, along with command-line arg parsing, to pick multiple json files, with just a bit of additional code, if required. Would u like me to edit answer for that ?